# How to get instance of typeclass from hackage?

Tags: haskell

Please tell me how to get an instance of it from any typeclass like [this page](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Show). Or you can get the typeclass from the type.
I know about TH, but I want to get an instance of that type from the any input.
I wish I could get it by communicating with Hackage, but I didn't know.

With TH, only types in scope could do that.
I want to get from Hackage because it is not realistic to import all modules.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's very difficult to understand what you're asking about here. Please sketch out the concrete problem that you're trying to solve, the code you have and what it is you need.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are no ways to retrieve the complete list of instances from Hackage.

The page you linked is a part of a documentation of `base` package, the package used as standard library of GHC.

These documentations are generated using [haddock](https://haskell-haddock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) tool. It can list the instances of a class or a type, by using knowledge collected during the build process of the package. But haddock *doesn't* list instances which aren't there while building the package.

Hackage is building all the packages it hosts and gives us the documentation using haddock. But (AFAIK) it just shows them separately, and does no further data kneading like making the list of instances of a class throughout Hackage.